# How do I use Guiding Light?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

Which skills on a monk is considered a direct healing spell that will trigger the damage boost from Guiding Light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be some confusing when it comes to the Guiding Light damage boost. When activated it doens't show any buff (none of the passive skills do btw). It works with the following three spells:

- Breath of Heaven
- Inner Sanctuary (with safe haven rune)
- Mantra of Healing

You can see the increased damage only when you watch your DPS. 
It also works on people that have full health.

Comment: what counts as an ally?  I tried breath of light on my summoned mystic ally and my DPS value did not change.

Comment: Followers such as the templar and mystic ally do not count as allies. Only real life players.

Comment: Pity there's no buff.